# Python Permission Error: [Errno 13] Writing to a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I'm a newbie when it comes to python programming. Appreciate any guidance on below.

Running a python game application on Windows and getting the following error:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\smith\python\game_tallies.csv'
[3328] Failed to execute script 'Blackjack4' due to unhandled exception!

Here's the related code. thanks

## update the game tally csv file

```
file_name = r'c:\smith\python\game_tallies.csv'

with open(file_name, mode='w', newline="", encoding='utf-8') as tally_file:
    tally_writer = csv.writer(tally_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"',   
            quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    tally_writer.writerow(['Banker Total','Player Total','Total Draws','Total 
            Surrenders'])
            tally_writer.writerow([str(banker_total_score), str(player_total_score),  
            str(draw_total), str(surrender_total)])

csv_file.close()
tally_file.close()
```

I've tried changing the permission of the csv file but no luck.

Comment: Can you confirm that the exception occurs when trying to open the file? btw... tally_file.close() is redundant

Comment: Most probably, you don't have the write permission to your directory (c:\smith\python). 
Try choosing another directory, e.g. local directory.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because you run the python script as a user that does not have the permission to open the file (That is why it says `permission denied`).
Check the file permissions and the permissions of the user that is running the script.

Comment: OP says that he has changed the permissions

Comment: He needs to check with which user he is running the script. It might be that it has lower privileges than the user he is using to change the permissions of the csv files.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using an absolute file path like 'c:\smith\python\game_tallies.csv', you can use a relative file path. Place the 'game_tallies.csv' file in the same directory as your Python script, and then modify your code like this:

```
import os

# Get the directory of the current script
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Construct the file path relative to the script directory
file_name = os.path.join(script_dir, 'game_tallies.csv')

# Rest of your code remains the same
```

Using a relative file path ensures that the script will look for the file in the same directory as the script, regardless of its absolute location.

Try these suggestions, and hopefully, you'll be able to resolve the permission error and write to the CSV file successfully.

Comment: Using a relative path works perfectly. Many thanks for the support.